# Getting data from 2 tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains details of a user (first name,last name etc) and a second table with each user's actions (IP) how can I get the last 100 connections to the system?

Thank you

Comment: is there any relation column between these two table? and which dbms please

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need join between two table and Top clause(SQL Server) or Limit Clause(Mysql)

```
select distinct  Top 100 ua.column1,ua.column2 from user_actions ua
inner join users u on ua.user_id = u.id;
```

For mysql

```
select distinct ua.column1,ua.column2 from user_actions ua
    inner join users u on ua.user_id = u.id 
    Limit 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are joined using a FOREIGN KEY on the UserActions Table, you can do a simple query:

```
select * from user_actions
inner join users on user_actions.user_id = users.id;
```

If you have no join however you could get all users in your code and iterate over each user and get its actions (not sure if you can do this in SQL, but you can in PHP etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like this, I assumed basic data needed if you can provide sample data and data structure of table can give specific answer. There are many functions like dense_rank, rank, rownumber or simple order by clause you can use I just showed one of the way.

```
drop table user_action;
drop table user_detail;

create table user_detail(userid NUMBER,username varchar2(100));
create table user_action(userid number,ipaddress varchar2(500),timestmp date);

insert into user_detail values (1,'ABC');
insert into user_detail values (2,'PQR');

insert into user_action values (1,'google.com',sysdate);
insert into user_action values (1,'google.com',sysdate-1);
insert into user_action values (1,'google.com',sysdate-2);

select * from (
  select userid, ipaddress, timestmp, row_number() 
    over (partition by ipaddress order by timestmp desc) rn 
  from user_detail 
  join user_action using (userid)) 
where rn <= 100;
```

Regards
Bhanu